# Swipe To Open Options ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, recycle-bin

I want to implement a listview, on which swiping opens up the `actions` that we can do with that item. I have attached an image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a demo for the same, please download and import.
If you are facing any issue then let me know.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8wy6zslt0cxeox/SwipeMenuListViewSample.rar?dl=0

Comment: Please let me know, if any query.

Answer (score 1):

Search on this site you will get lot of swipe listview library here

http://android-arsenal.com/free?sort=name

Comment: Found Few.Thanx. But i wanna know which is the most preferred.